# pandas: KeyError in one case, but not in another similar case

Tags: python, pandas

Why do I get a KeyError in one case, but not the other?  See below.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index=list('abcd'))
>>> s2 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index=list('acbd'))
>>> s1.loc['a':'z']
a    10
b    20
c    30
d    40
dtype: int64
>>> s2.loc['a':'z']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 559, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 564, in _get_with
    indexer = self.index._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind='getitem')
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 871, in _convert_slice_indexer
    key, is_index_slice=is_index_slice)
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 806, in _convert_slice_indexer_getitem
    return self._convert_slice_indexer(key)
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 893, in _convert_slice_indexer
    indexer = self.slice_indexer(start, stop, step)
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2346, in slice_indexer
    start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2496, in slice_locs
    end_slice = self.get_slice_bound(end, 'right', kind)
  File "/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2438, in get_slice_bound
    raise err
KeyError: 'z'
```

Update:
One of the answers said that this could be because `s1.index.is_monotonic` is true.  But here is a case where `is_monotonic` is `False`, but there is no `KeyError`.

```
>>> s3 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index=list('dcba'))
>>> s3['z':'a']
d    10
c    20
b    30
a    40
dtype: int64
>>> s3.index.is_monotonic
False
```

Python v2.7.5, pandas v0.16.1

Comment: I can confirm that 0.16.1 exhibits the behavior you describe. Oddly, pandas 0.15.2 gives an error for both DataFrames: `'stop bound [z] is not in the [index]'`.

Comment: Regarding your update: `s3.index.is_monotonic_decreasing` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes down to the fact that the index for `t` is not monotonic, i.e. it's not sorted. Sorted/monotonic indexes allow for a few behaviours that are not possible for unsorted ones.

```
s.index.is_monotonic
Out[15]: True

t.index.is_monotonic
Out[16]: False
```

This is briefly mentioned in the [docs on multi-indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex), although obviously that doesn't quite apply in your case, I'm not sure where to go for a good overview of how slicing works for sorted/unsorted indices.

Comment: Good to know about `is_monotonic`, but the following case succeeds in spite of is_monotonic being false:
>>> s2 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index=list('dcba'))
>>> s2['d':'a']
d    10
c    20
b    30
a    40
dtype: int64
>>> s2.index.is_monotonic
False
I'll edit the post to reflect this.